# Re-bind alt left/right in nano

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, nano

I'd like to rebind the alt-left and alt-right keybindings in nano, can't seem to get it to work. I'm on ubuntu 16.04

my `~/.nanorc` file:

```
bind M-right nextword main
bind M-left prevword main
```

version info:

```
GNU nano, version 2.5.3
(C) 1999..2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Email: nano@nano-editor.org Web: http://www.nano-editor.org/
Compiled options: --disable-libmagic --disable-wrapping-as-root --enable-utf8
```

Comment: Taking a quick look at src/global.c where the detaults are loaded, it seemed to me that either "M-Left" (with uppercase L) or "M-←" (with U+2190, that's what's encoded in UTF-8 there) would work, however, they don't (in accordance with the docs as shown in Thomas's answer). I recommend that you file a bug / feature request in nano's bugtracker at https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=nano.

Comment: So I'm looking at the nano source and I found this:
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/global.c?id=4aec1649f530147f72e3d04a7e908411d39e063a#n1147
(Line 1147)
This doesn't seem to work though :/
```bind M-\xE2\x86\x90 nextword main
bind M-\xE2\x86\x92 prevword main```
Anyone know c?

Comment: The C compiler interprets those `\x` escapes, and it becomes the raw UTF-8 representation of '←' as I've shown above.

Comment: See also http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51685#comment3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see messages like `[ backup files enabled ]` when you try those shortcuts, it means they are producing Alt+B and Alt+F escape sequences. So you can just rebind those like so:

```
unbind M-B all 
bind M-B prevword main 
unbind M-F all 
bind M-F nextword main
```

See [this bug report thread](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51685#comment4) for more info.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much for this! I added it to my .nanorc and I can finally move around in my files like a normal human being.
I literally created an account to thank you. So thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because

- *nano* does not have a way to bind the cursor-keys (*left*, *right*, *up*, *down*), and
- those keys do not correspond to a *character*, and
- your cursor-keys  send a character sequence which *nano* does not understand.

Referring to the [manual](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.8/nano.html#Rebinding-Keys):

> The format of *key* should be one of:
>
> **`^`**  followed by an ASCII character or the word "Space". Example: **`^C`**.
> **`M-`**  followed by a ASCII character or the word "Space". Example: **`M-C`**.
> **`F`**  followed by a numeric value from 1 to 16. Example: **`F10`**.

The manual also mentions that you can use an *escape* character before the ASCII character when entering a *key*, though that would not help in this case because your cursor-keys send several ASCII characters, e.g.,

<kbd>*escape*</kbd><kbd>**`[`**</kbd><kbd>**`1`**</kbd><kbd>**`;`**</kbd><kbd>**`3`**</kbd><kbd>**`D`**</kbd>

for the "Alt-left" which several terminal emulators (beginning with xterm) use.